# CloudCompare fails to launch with error: “QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0”

Tags: linux, qt

In the last week, CloudCompare has suddenly stopped launching. When trying to launch via desktop icon, nothing happens. When trying to launch via commandline (e.g. `$ cloudcompare.CloudCompare`) nothing happens and I get the following error:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Trying to launch CloudCompare with `sudo`/as root user returns a slightly different error message:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
```

Having looked around Github, here and various other forums, this seems to be a problem that people have encountered with other programs that use Qt and/or OpenGL (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39478208/qxcbconnection-could-not-connect-to-display-when-trying-to-debug-linux-app-wit), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979185/qt-5-1-qapplication-without-display-qxcbconnection-could-not-connect-to-displ), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924997/pyqt5-could-not-connect-to-display)). I also realise that this isn't really enough information to debug the problem, so if there is any other diagnostic info I can/should provide, let me know and I will add it.

### My Environment

- **OS & Version:** Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- **CC Version:** v2.8.1 (latest)
- **Graphics card:** Intel Haswell Mobile
- **Qt version:** 5.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Newer systems by design don't allow graphical applications as root (it's a Wayland thing). Workaround:

```
$ xhost si:localuser:root
$ sudo ...your-graphical-app...
```

Restore the default permissions:

```
$ xhost -si:localuser:root
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! I haven't encountered the problem since re-installing CloudCompare, but if it happens again I will certainly try this and report back.